Why is MS project 2019 task not reflecting the finish date of the predecessor it is connected to?

As you can see, both dependencies are task four but they are not starting concurrently. Why is this?

Brandon Wu, Sorry but I don't see any dependencies, just dates and un-named field columns. But the main thing I notice is the tasks show as 100% so we can't tell how it got there and that's the critical important part. If you provide additional information showing the dependencies and what the plan looks like before the 100% completion, then maybe we can provide some insight.

As @john-project said in the comments, task 7 is 100% complete; that means there are already actual values for start and finish dates.
However, I can see that tasks 6 and 7 have assigned resources (but the image does not show the complete list of resources). I'm pretty sure that there is, at least, one work resource assigned to both tasks; if that is the case, then Project moved task 7 to start after task 6 finish date, as a result of resource leveling (in order to solve work overallocation).
Check the assigned resources. Also check Project's resource leveling settings and disable automatic leveling if you want to avoid that behavior.
Hope that helps. Greetings.

I changed my % completed value as you pointed out that task 7 was already complete, fixed the problem. Didn't know MS Project had auto levelling. THX!

Yes, Project has auto levelling for work resources with overallocation. It is disabled by default, but if you use another Project file as a template, it is possible that the file has that option enabled. I'm glad it helped.
